# How to hide .js and .map files in WebStorm while working on Angular2-typescript project

Tags: typescript, angular, webstorm

I tried adding the extensions to `.gitignore` but the result is as below:

[image: webstorm file explorer]

The files are not completely hidden.

Comment: do you have typescript compiler enabled ?

Comment: You can create custom scope where you include all files but exclude any with those extensions. Then use that scope in Project View panel instead of default "Project". IDE can also nest those generated file under parent .ts node .. but it can only be done if you are using any built-in compiler / file watcher (in other words -- when IDE participates in some way in compiling them and knows that those files must be grouped)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

When using WebStorm without the built-in TypeScript Compiler (e.g. because you are running an Angular2 project with their `npm start` script which does the compiling already) and the other method doesn't work, you can configure your own filtered "Project" panel for WebStorm:

1. Select `Project Files` section of the side panel (`Project` section does not offer the needed config menu)
2. Click on the gear icon to configure [image]
3. Select "Edit Scopes" from that menu
4. Add a new Scope
5. Set the Pattern to an appropriate filter to exclude the `*.js` and `*.js.map` files (I am using `!file[my-root-folder]:app//*.js&&!file[my-root-folder]:app//*.js.map`)
6. You can select this scope as a section of the side panel (instead of `Project` or `Project Files`) under the name you set the scope.

Comment: Great answer. Although you can actually use a simpler pattern too. Something like this:
 `!file:app/*.js*`
this omits files that include **js** in their extension (`*.js` and `*.js.map` files) under the **app** folder

Comment: The trick before thinking this does not work is to make sure to do step 6...I won't tell you how i found this out :) When I followed all steps it worked for me. I used the shorthand filter. I called mine 'NG2 Project' Thanks all!

Comment: @KiaPanahiRad Minor issue, but *.js also includes .json files, which probably should not be hidden (realized this when started wondering where my .json files had gone...)

Comment: @JuhaPalomäki Oops! You're right, I just didn't have `json` and `js` files alongside each other in the same folder I guess. Good point though.

Answer (score 11):

- **Enable Typescript Compiler** (Generated files are hidden when compiler generates them)

[image]

- **Change your view to `Project`** as suggested by **Cibes**

[image]

Answer (score 10):

For me, using the `Project` panel, rather than the `Project Files` panel did the trick collapsing the `*.js` and `.js.map` files and hiding them beneath their corresponding `*.ts` file.

[image]

Note: This is only working when WebStorm's TypeScript Compiler is enabled. ([see A_Singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36200444/1473411))

Answer (score 7):

**WebStorm 2017.3.3**

If you don't need run **Enable Typescript Compiler**.

You can do this

[image]

Then

[image]

After that, just select you filter

[image]

Comment: My silly face missed the part where one needs to select it. Thanks for adding the pictures!