# In IntelliJ IDEA, how can you filter JS files out of "Find Usage" results when using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea

Is there a way to configure IntelliJ IDEA so that when you transpile code from TypeScript to Javascript, it ignores the Javascript files in search results and most importantly omit them in ***Find Usages*** results?

In doing so, however, it would also be important to keep JS results that are NOT transpiled from TypeScript (ie: the ones originally written in JS, not TS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to hide .js and .map files in WebStorm while working on Angular2-typescript project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183470/how-to-hide-js-and-map-files-in-webstorm-while-working-on-angular2-typescript)
By using the first answer stated there, you could exclude the native JS files and include all other JS files as it seems.